# How to allow icmp for your machine?

Tags: iptables, icmp

I want to allow icmp (ping) for my server. I was reading about IPTables and read that to allow a ping to your machine, you need to have INPUT rule as well as a FORWARD rule. Because INPUT only handles input and for routing of ping, you will need to enable it on the FORWARD chain.

I was told by my colleagues that we iptables to configure the permissions. So I assume we use ipv6 then. I was told that there is a INPUT rule, but still ping does not work. Thats when I was wondering if it requires a corrosponding FORWARD rule as well. Is there anyway to troubleshoot this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you disabled it, ping is there by default.

Comment: @NasirRiley, so do you mean even if there is no entry for icmp in IPTables, ping will still work?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried pinging the server? Virtually every OS allows ping by default.

Answer (score 5):

First off: I guess by "server" you mean GNU/Linux-based server, and "ping" meant conventional IPv4 ICMP echo request?

Ping is usually allowed by default.

To check if IPv4 ping transponder is enabled on GNU/Linux-based server, run following command on your server:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

It should output `0` which means ping is **enabled**, i.e. IPv4 ICMP echo request is not ignored.

- But in an unlikely case that it did output `1` (which means ping is *disabled*), run following command on your server *as root*:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
  ```

  And your server should now respond to IPv4 ping. If you would like it to be pemanent across reboot, add this line to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

  ```
  net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
  ```

---

P.S. IPv6 ping is a different beast, and that is the one which will need an `iptables` configuration to tame.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I was told by my colleagues that we iptables to configure the permissions. So I assume we use ipv6 then. I was told that there is a INPUT rule, but still ping does not work. Thats when I was wondering if it requires a corrosponding FORWARD rule as well. Is there anyway to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: @csharpnewbie, `iptables` _can_ be used for filtering IPv4 ping, when you need finer control than wholesale ON/OFF.

Comment: @csharpnewbie, and the fact that "_I was told by my colleagues that we iptables to configure the permissions_" and "_I was told that there is a INPUT rule_" **should have been included in the question, _seriously_**. Go edit your question to include it, or else no one would be able to answer it properly.

Comment: Since it is now obvious that this is an access-control list problem; @csharpnewbie, you cannot expect anyone to suggest a "fix" to your existing firewall rules, without showing them the existing rules you have in place; that's why you got downvotes on your question.

Comment: So while you are at it @csharpnewbie, **run `iptables -n -L INPUT | grep icmp` and `iptables -n -L OUTPUT | grep icmp` on your server as _root_**, then append their output to the end of your question. Make sure that you tab-indent them as two separate code blocks, and label them properly. I will follow up with a _different_ answer if I could make sense of the output.